# Rails asset pipeline: Standard way for including all /vendor/assets/javascripts/?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I've been transitioning an app to Rails 3.1 (and now on to 3.2) and watched the [Railscast on the asset pipeline](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline). I moved all of my third-party jquery plugin files to the /vendor/assets/javascripts/ directory. In my /app/assets/javascripts/application.js I have the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

I realized the `require_tree .` call only loads the tree for the /app/assets/javascripts/ directory. (Is that correct?) What's the best way to include *all* the "vendor" javascripts? (I'm not worried about ordering at this point.) Of course I could require them line by line in /app/assets/javascripts/application.js. My other thought was to create /vendor/assets/javascripts/vendor_javascripts.js with the following:

```
//= require_tree .
```

And then in /app/assets/javascripts/application.js add the following:

```
//= require vendor_javascripts
```

This seems a little clunky though. Is there a better way to automatically include all the "vendor" (and/or "lib") javascripts?

PS. I saw [this about index.js files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#using-index-files), but I would potentially end up with multiple files named index.js, right? Oh, and I tried restarting my server throughout.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can add something like this in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file to include all the vendor javascripts:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
```

Comment: Forgot about the whole relative paths thing :) Thank you, works great!

Comment: Actually, I think the OP's suggested approach is less clunky

Comment: I recommend just adding a `vendor` folder under `app/assets`. The `vendor/assets` thing just seems unnecessary.

Comment: I tend to agree, but Rails' default layout for a new app gives you `vendor/assets` so I think many will try to make that work :/

Answer (score 21):

I know it's an old question, but you can create a manifest file on the vender/assets/javascript folder:

```
 #vendor/assets/javascripts/my_jquery_plugins/manifest.js
 # require_tree .
```

And in you application.js:

```
 //= require my_jquery_plugins/manifest.js
```

If you're using Rails 4, name the `manifest.js` as `index.js` and in your `application.js`:

```
//= require my_jquery_plugins
```

It's less hacky than relative path described.