# Rails asset pipeline not including required files in application.js manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

The rails asset pipeline isn't including files required in application.js.

The only javascript file rendered to the browser is application.js, and the require lines are not compiled to include tags as they should be:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .

;
```

in config/application.rb I have `config.assets.enable = true`

I'm using rails 3.2.8, and I've tried ruby 1.9.3-p398 and 2.0.0-p0 installed using rvm.

How do I get application.js to include the files required?

EDIT: It looks like the lock on this question was recently unlocked, and activity has increased. It has been a while since I worked on this, and the code doesn't exist anymore. If I am remembering correctly I reinstalled ruby and rails and that fixed the problem.

Should I close this question? What is the proper procedure in this situation?

Comment: @iRichLau How Do I fix it? I wan't application.js to include the files in the manefest

Comment: all your js files in assets are automatically loaded in rails because of the //require_tree .

Comment: I know they should, but they aren't being loaded. The only assets that get sent to the browser are application.css, and application.js, and neither include any of the files in their manifests.

Comment: have you tried restarting the server? also you can manually require the js. by addinig another //=require 'nivo-slider.js'

Comment: I've restarted the server, created new apps and explicitly required the files. I think the pipeline is not compiling the manifest.

Comment: Same issue here. It's a shame this was closed..

Comment: @Trip I'm not completely sure what fixed it, I reinstalled RVM, and upgraded the rails version. Everything works now.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Same thing for me as well

Comment: Having the same problem! Why did casperOne close this??

Comment: There's got to be more to this problem than just a faulty JS file -- can I ask how you are compiling your assets, where you are pushing to production & what problems you're seeing?

Comment: Perhaps that foreign ; semi-colon caused the issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I answered this here:

[Rails 3.2.8 Application.js and Application.css are not working as expcted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733991/rails-3-2-8-application-js-and-application-css-are-not-working-as-expcted/20711074#20711074)

Here's the text:

> I was also having this issue but with newer versions of Rails and
>   Ruby.
>
> Examining the log, I was being served javascript.js from Rails cache
>   as the server didn't see a change in the file. I went and moved the
>   require lines around (just one) to tell Rails that there's a change in
>   the file and re-compile/use. Wellm that did it for me!
>
> Hope it helps somebody.

Another important finding is to upgrade your sprockets gem in your Gemfile.

I had version 2.2.1 and had issues, after upgrading to 2.2.2, it worked

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.2.2'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! TXS @Isaffie

Comment: @everett1992 do you think this answers your question? If so, could you mark it as so? Thanks

Comment: Updating sprockets from `2.2.1` to `~> 2.2.2` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are upgrading from 3.0.x - 3.1.x and run in to this issue upgrade to 3.2.x and It may solve this issue.

I recently upgraded an app from 3.0 - 3.1.12 and found the asset manifest would not work using Ruby 1.9.3, Ruby 2.0, or Ruby 2.1.1.  I then went ahead and upgraded to 3.2.17 and everything seems to be working correctly using Ruby 2.1.1.

Hopefully this helps anyone else that may run in to this issue upgrading.

Comment: I can confirm this seems to have done the trick - upgraded from ruby 1.9.3 to 2.1.5 and things broke on rails 3.2.6, fixed when I upgraded to rails 3.2.21.

Comment: Also seemed to work for me. May be related to sprockets above (Installing sprockets 2.2.3 (was 2.1.4))

Answer (score 1):

One common reason for this is that the assets are compiled and found in public/assets, in which case Rails will not recompile them. If you have assets in here, and have not set config.serve_static_assets to false, then Rails will not recompile your assets:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

So if you have precompiled stuff in public/assets, either delete them, or add the above line to development.rb

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy/paste your bootstrap files into the vendor/assets folder, or into app/assets?  The asset pipeline only includes the app/assets folder by default, not lib/assets or vendor/assets.  To include vendor/assets in the pipeline, enter this command into your app/assets/javascript/application.js file:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/
```

To do the same for your CSS files:

```
*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/
```

I know it says in the comments at the top of the file that any file in the app, lib or vendor folders will be included, but I've found this wasn't the case.  I can't explain why, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006823/rails-asset-pipeline-standard-way-for-including-all-vendor-assets-javascripts) for my source.  Try the above commands, or include the bootstrap files in your app/assets folders.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This question was recently reopened, I don't have the code anymore so I can't do diagnostics anymore. What is proper  etiquette in this situation?

Comment: Sorry, proper etiquette in terms of what?  Awarding an answer, up/downvoting, or something else?  If you mean one of those things, I would guess the choice is yours, since the question is yours.  Your actions indicate your opinion of the answer. :-)