# Why are js files in my rails asset pipeline not being compiled?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am experiencing a problem similar to this question: 
[Rails asset pipeline not including required files in application.js manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328569/rails-asset-pipeline-not-including-required-files-in-application-js-manifest) However, that question was closed, so I am re-asking it, but with the specifics of my situation.)

### Environment:

Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 3.2.8, OSX 10.7.5, Chrome 28.0.1500.95

### The main problem I am experiencing

Files placed in "/app/assets/javascripts" do not appear to be compiling to or appearing in "/public/assets"

### An Example

If I place a file such as this test.js file in app/assets/javascripts:

```
  alert("Hello!");
```

and then reload a page in my app, this alert should appear. (I am replicating what Ryan Bates does in his [Railscast on the Asset Pipeline](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline) at ~6:30 into the video) However, no alert appears.

### Debugging attempts

Some tests I did to try to debug this.

- (As recommended by @Aidan below) If I "rm -rf public/assets", then
  add "javascript_include_tag 'test'" to my layout, the alert *does*
  appear. However, maybe because I'm a n00b, I don't know how that
  helps me debug the problem.
- If I add //= require_test to app/javascripts/application.js to my
  manifest file, this does *not* result in the alert appearing.

### My manifest file (app/javascripts/application.js)

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
// removed /sitewide from require_tree
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

### My application.rb file

```
 # Enable the asset pipeline
 config.assets.enabled = true
```

### Rails console output for "y Rails.application.config.assets.paths"

```
"/Users/Anders/Dropbox/dev/suggestion-box-app/app/assets/images",
 "/Users/Anders/Dropbox/dev/suggestion-box-app/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/Users/Anders/Dropbox/dev/suggestion-box-app/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/Users/Anders/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@suggestion-box-app/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts",
 "/Users/Anders/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@suggestion-box-app/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts"
```

### My views/layouts/application.html.haml file

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}/
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width", :name => "viewport"}/
    %meta{:content => "yes", :name => "apple-mobile-web-app-capable"}/
    %title My App
    %script{:type=>"text/javascript", :src=>"//use.typekit.net/wjb6ybj.js"}
    :javascript
      try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}
    = stylesheet_link_tag "screen", :media => "all"
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
  %body
    #container
      = render "layouts/flashes"
      = yield
      = render "layouts/footer"
```

### Source from an app page viewed in localhost:3000

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta content='width=device-width' name='viewport'>
    <meta content='yes' name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable'>
    <title>My app</title>
    <script src='//use.typekit.net/wjb6ybj.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script>
      try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}
    </script>
    <link href="/assets/screen.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="FqMtH+rs6or9HRx+RL4bWpQyLTNPM8BKLrcf/xZknP8=" name="csrf-token" />
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='container'>
      ....
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### What I see when viewing "localhost:3000/assets/application.js"

```
    /*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2005, 2012 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2013-2-4
 */
(function(e,t){function P(e){var t=e.length,n=b.type(e);return b.isWindow(e)?!1:e.nodeType===1&&t?!0:n==="array"||n!=="function"&&(t===0||typeof t=="number"&&t>0&&t-1 in e)}function B(e){var t=H[e]={};return b.each(e.match(E)||[],function(e,n){t[n]=!0}),t}function I(e,n,r,i){if(!b.acceptData(e))return;var s,o,u=b.expando,a=typeof n=="string",f=e.nodeType,c=f?
```

[...remainder of jquery excluded]

*Should I not see the test.js file here?*

Any suggestions as to what the problem might be?  Is there any additional info I can provide to help debug this issue? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have a file in `public/assets/application.js`? Run `rake assets:clean` to make sure you don't.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not have any impact.

Comment: Try a few things, just to make sure it can find that file: 1) `rm -rf public/assets`, 2) remove `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` from `application.js`, and 3) add `javascript_include_tag "test"` to your layout.

Comment: @AidanFeldman - thanks for this suggestion.  I did all of the above, and upon page refresh, the "hello!" alert now appears(!)

Comment: K, well that's good... now work your way backwards and see where the problem is!  I imagine it was step #1.

Comment: Could it be because of no blank line at the end of the manifest file?

Ref:

    // WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
    // GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem appears to have been related to my rails/gem versions.  After updating from Rails 3.2.8 to Rails 3.2.14 (which also required updating the rack gem from 1.4.1 to 1.4.5) the issue was resolved and items in assets/javascripts are now being compiled/added to public/assets.  Note that I created a completely new gemset as part doing this, so the issue may have had nothing to do with the Rails version and simply was a questions of a "corrupted" gem set that needed to be re-created.

Answer (score 2):

Rails will compile all the targets listed in [`config.assets.precompile`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets). These targets will be compiled to `public/assets/`. That config item already includes `"application.js"` and other some targets, so you need to add any *other* targets you want to be precompiled to `public/assets/`. The source file to be compiled for any particular target are automatically computed based on the name of the target; e.g., a target of `test.js` would be compiled from `app/assets/javascripts/test.js` or from `app/assets/javascripts/test.js.coffee`, whichever exists.

Comment: Maybe I am asking the wrong question.  I simply want JS files I place in assets/javascripts to be accessible in public/assets.  My understanding is that this should be handled by including //= require_tree . in the manifest file.  So I guess I'm not understanding your answer.  Could you maybe explain it differently?

Comment: @andersr you seem to understand clearly that `test.js` should be included in the `application.js` file from your `require_tree .` line. @yfeldblum's answer isn't really relevant here; you don't need to modify `config.assets.precompile` to get `test.js` included in your `application.js` file.  What you **should** see in development is every `.js` file dependency included from your `=require_tree .` line added to your layout's HTML source as separate `<script>` tags. One of **these** tags should be for your `test.js` file.

Comment: The above comment assumes you a) are in `:development`, b) have `config.assets.debug = true`, and c) are including your script tag in your layout with `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Comment: @Deefour thanks for your clarifications.  Yes, I am in development and I have the javascript include tag in my view.  I added the exact markup above for your reference.  However, I do not have config.assets.debug = true.  Would that go in /config/application.rb?

Comment: That goes in `config/environments/development.rb` typically.

Comment: @Deefour - checked config/environments/development.rb and config.assets.debug = true

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34697/discussion-between-deefour-and-andersr)

Comment: @yfeldblum's answer was relevant for me. The question title and description have some content that drives to other problems too. Dont be so excludent to Question and answers purposes...