# Rails 3.2.8 - not loading assets (development)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have searched around and can't rectify the situation based on the responses to other similar questions. I seem to have broken the asset pipeline somehow but can't seem to figure out how.

None of my assets are being loaded at all; rails seems to just be ignoring my manifest files. When I inspect my page in firebug, only the 'non-compiled' text inside my manifest files (both js and css) is being displayed - almost as if the asset pipeline wasn't even enabled.

I deleted the contents of public/assets since I was adding a new file to the manifest which seemed to start this behavior.

Current configuration:

**environments/development.rb**

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

**application.rb**

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.manifest = config.root

# Add extra assets for precompiling
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css']

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with js or jquery.

Comment: assets are not compiled in development mode by default.

Comment: @parchment - My mistake, I put it there because it's the javascript/jquery which isn't loading. You're right - this is a rails issue.

Comment: @GhostRider Reading the Rails documentation of the asset pipeline I was lead to believe that assets in app/assets would be loaded in separate script tags as per the option 'config.assets.debug = true'? Do correct me if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by using an incompatible version of ruby. I was using version 2.1.2 which lead to unusual behavior from the sprockets gem (which powers the asset pipeline). This was fixed by downgrading to ruby 1.9.3. I haven't done any experimentation for fear of breaking it again but maybe this has been addressed in later versions of sprockets. I am using sprockets 2.1.3.

See: [Rails 3.2.8 Application.js and Application.css are not working as expcted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733991/rails-3-2-8-application-js-and-application-css-are-not-working-as-expcted)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. You can still use Ruby 2.1.2, just upgrade rails to latest 3.2.x version - it's 3.2.22

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.22'
```

And run:

```
$ bundle update rails
```

Answer (score 1):

Always remember two things when you want to handle Rails asset pipleline:-

1. if you want all you newly created js/css to autoinclude in `application.js/css`,pls add them in...
   **ELSE**
2. IF you dont wont to add in `manifest` file(`application.js/css`) then use `precompile directive` in yuur environment file.

   `config.assets.precompile=%w(custom.css,custom2.js...etc)`

so make sure you have either of these...

**===========for example=-=============**

suppose you have new `css/js` file:- 
`custom.css` inside

```
app/assets/stylesheets/
```

so you can include in

```
application.css

// = require 'custom'
```

**OR**

use **precompile directive**:-

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( custom.css )
```

and then reference it like you always do

```
stylesheet_link_tag "custom"
```

same applies for js also

Comment: All of my js is included in the manifest - it's just not being loaded. I have all the necessary //= require lines.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a few hours troubleshooting this issue (in 2017!) and it turned out I just needed to remove the gem `active_reload`. Updating rails and ruby was having no effect for me. The thread where I found that gold is here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2715