# Does require_tree require files inside 'vendor/assets' and 'lib/assets' ? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I came to know that during pre-compilation of assets in production mode, Rails will take assets from '`app/assets`' only by default if we do not require files explictly from  any other specific sources like '`vendor/assets`' and '`lib/assets`'.

I've a question:

> Will **require_tree .** load assets from 'vendor/assets' and 'lib/assets'
>   ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `require_tree .` will only load the assets in the local directory, hence the dot after `require_tree`, which specifies only the directory where the application asset file exists. If you want to include files in `vendor/assets` and `lib/assets`, you should do something like this (or similar for stylesheets):

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
//= require_tree ../../../lib/assets/javascripts/.
```

(From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006823/rails-asset-pipeline-standard-way-for-including-all-vendor-assets-javascripts).)