# how to effectively organize vendor css and js files togheter in rails assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

(I'm new both to Rails and SO, so excuse if I'm not doing it right)

I am trying to adapt a regular third-party web template in my rails 4 application. I have a *vendor* folder with other files and subfolders like *bootstrap.js*, *Nivo-slider* and *Isotope* which contain both .css and .js files.

So I moved all files and subfolders to `vendor/assets` and included `//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/` in my *application.js*, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006823/rails-asset-pipeline-standard-way-for-including-all-vendor-assets-javascripts). So my application.js looks like

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/
//= require_tree .
```

And in my *layout* file:

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "application.css" -%>
<%=javascript_include_tag "application" -%>
```

when I execute it on my server I get *Sprockets::FileOutsidePaths* exception:

`Showing /home/valle/RoR/grifo/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #25 raised:
/home/valle/RoR/grifo/vendor/assets/bootstrap.js isn't in paths: /home/valle/RoR/grifo/app/assets/images, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/app/assets/javascripts, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/app/assets/stylesheets, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/circle-flip-slideshow, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/isotope, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/javascripts, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/jflickrfeed, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/magnific-popup, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/mediaelement, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/nivo-slider, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/owl-carousel, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/rs-plugin, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/stylesheets, /home/valle/RoR/grifo/lib/assets/twitterjs, /home/valle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/modernizr-rails-2.7.1/vendor/assets/javascripts, /home/valle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/turbolinks-2.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts, /home/valle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts, /home/valle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts, /home/valle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-663760e67b80/app/assets/fonts, /home/valle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-663760e67b80/app/assets/images, /home/valle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-663760e67b80/app/assets/javascripts, /home/valle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-663760e67b80/app/assets/stylesheets, /home/valle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-663760e67b80/vendor/assets/stylesheets`

I thought Sprockets would take all js or css files in all assets folders, precompile, unify and minify them, but now it seems I need to specify the path. How could I solve it?
Besides, is it a problem not to have separated javascript and css folders in vendors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `rails 4` they have removed `vendor` folder,so,assets will not server from vendor.

in that `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` not contains `vendor`,if you want you have to add the path like

in config/application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply. It seems to work like a charm.
Still, vendor folder does exist (at least in rails 4.1.0) and I don't get why it was removed from `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` anyhow. Shouldn't I use `vendor/folders`? What is the correct alternative to use my third-party files then?

Comment: Since version 4 vendor and lib directories are not included in the asset pipeline by default.if you want to then you should extend assets path or use `app/assets` folder.if my answer is helpful accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update **application.js** file as

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require otherJsFiles
```

And in **application.css** file require other css file as

```
*= require otherCssFiles
```

Require each js and css file in application.js and application.css file placed in **vendor/assets**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solutions seems to work, although I did not test it. Requiring each file seems to be very tedious and not much like Rails style. It makes me wonder if Rails assets pipeline does worth it to be used instead of regular calling files directly in my HTML code.
Besides, I do not understand why would `vendor/assets` exist as a built in folder.

Comment: vendor/assets folder is used to add thirt party css and javascript files. vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks. It is in rails 3.2