# Can´t add JavaScript to rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Im trying to add jquery.validate.min.js to my rails application. I have copied the file to

vendor/assets/javascripts

Added it to application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.validate.min
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require jquery.ddslick
```

And my application.html.erb has

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/jquery.validate.min" %>
```

But i get a 404 error for the jquery.validate.min.js

What did do wrong ?

Comment: Can you try something like the accepted answer in this question.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006823/rails-asset-pipeline-standard-way-for-including-all-vendor-assets-javascripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006823/rails-asset-pipeline-standard-way-for-including-all-vendor-assets-javascripts)

Answer (score 0):

If are using application.js you don't need to call this in layouts

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/jquery.validate.min" %>
```

But you need to have

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

If you want to manually load the `jquery.validate.min` then you need to add it to the precompile list

```
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.validate.min.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

Hope that helps